# Read in N xls files, mutate a new column to each indicating date and then row bind to a single data frame

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I have 4 xls files that I wish to read into a single data frame.

Each file represents a distinct time period i.e. Q1 2020, Q2 2020, Q3 2020 and Q4 2020 but the xls files are named Jan 2020.xls, April 2020.xls, July 2020.xls and December 2020.xls

I wish to read these 4 files into a single data frame but I wish to add a new column "DATECOL" which indicates which quarter and year each file is from.

```
# CREATE A LIST OF FILES FOR IMPORTING
file.list <- list.files(path = "Libby ASP",pattern = '*.xls', full.names = TRUE)

asp.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel, col_types = c("text","text","text","text","text")) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

For simplicity I have specified the data type as text for all fields to avoid any issue when binding rows.

How can I mutate a new column to each file indicating the date info i.e. Q1 2020 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `basename` of the 'file.list' to `yearqtr`, `format` it, and use `map2` to loop over the 'asp.list', and the corresponding new yearqtr formatted values, and `mutate` to create a new column

```
library(zoo)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

nm1 <- format(as.yearqtr(basename(file.list), "%b %Y.xls"), "Q%q %Y")
asp.list <- map(file.list, read_excel, 
                 col_types = c("text","text","text","text","text"))
asp.list2 <- map2(asp.list, nm1, ~ .x %>% 
                    mutate(date = .y))
```

---

Or this can be done while reading the file itself

```
asp.data <- map_dfr(file.list, ~ read_excel(.x, 
         col_types = c("text","text","text","text","text")) %>%
         mutate(date = format(as.yearqtr(basename(.x), "%b %Y.xls"), "Q%q %Y")))
```

Comment: wow! just wow! I wish I had your understanding of the language. Thank you so much this was a massive help, thanks again.

Comment: @TheGoat Glad to help you.

Comment: I'm very sorry I thought I had accepted the answer, my apologies.

Comment: @TheGoat It's okay.  Just wanted to remind if you forgot. thank you